Can I travel to Malaysia from Singapore?
I am from India and we are planning to visit Singapore.
I would like to know, what would be the procedure(legal) to travel to Malaysia from Singapore. I would like to know if I hold a valid Singapore visa(travel) and would also like to go to Malaysia via road(bus), will it be legal for me to just get on a bus to Malaysia and just show Indian Passport when asked?
Note: Malaysia is visa free for Indian travelers, and the below web page says the list of required documents needed when travelling to Malaysia from India. Will this still be valid for an Indian to travel from Singapore?
https://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_new-delhi/home/-/asset_publisher/zjzc18WNnQto/blog/visa-free-travel-to-malaysia-for-indian-citizens?inheritRedirect=false

Yes, this is allowed.
Malaysia applies the same policies at its land borders as it does at air borders, so if you can enter visa-free, you can also do so by land from Singapore or other land borders.
Make sure to have proof of onward or return travel, as sometimes Indian citizens are given more scrutiny than travelers of other nationalities, even when the law says they are to be treated the same. If your route home passes through Singapore again, also make sure that your Singaporean visa is valid for multiple entries.
Note also that the visa exemption for Indian citizens to Malaysia is a temporary measure currently set to expire at the end of December 2024, so if your planned travel is after that date, you will have to check if the exemption gets extended and to apply for an e-visa if it does not.

Thank you! @mlc
